# Communication between hyperledger ordering services

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

This question is about orderers in different organizations. Is there any communication happens between two orderers of two different organizations? If so, how can we configure that and how does the consensus work?
(OR)
Is every organization has its own ordering service with multiple orderer nodes isolated from other organizations?

Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only 1 ordering 'service'. This service is composed of several orderers. Usually just 3 or 5. All orderers communicate with the Kafka cluster which tells all the orderers what is included in a block. The orderers then send the new blocks to the peers. Peers may use any of the orderers. It is recommended to have all orderers within one Org. But I have run a configuration with 2 orderers in 1 org and 1 orderer in another org and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was watching a video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_RgCfjunEU how hyperledger fabic works.

Comment: Cont...from previous comment. In the example network, there are two Orgs and each org has its own orderer. I understand from your answer that these two orderers belong to one ordering service.